# How can I mount a VDI with snapshot?

Tags: mount, virtualbox, snapshot

Working on Linux Mint 18.1, VirtualBox 5.0.40_Ubuntu.

I have a VDI file from a VirtualBox VM:

```
~/VirtualBox\ VMs/Win10x64/Win10x64.vdi
```

I've taken a Snapshot:

```
~/VirtualBox\ VMs/Win10x64/Snapshots/{GUID}.vdi
```

I want to mount the guest's HDD **from the snapshot**.

I can successfully mount the base VDI using `qemu-nbd`:

```
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/Win10x64/Win10x64.vdi
```

But if I try with the Snapshot file:

```
qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 ~/VirtualBox\ VMs/Win10x64/Snapshots/{GUID}.vdi
```

it fails with:

```
unsupported VDI image (non-NULL link UUID)
```

I did notice the `--snapshot` parameter for `qemu-nbd` but this doesn't seem to be the right thing.

How can I mount the HDD as it is in the snapshot?

**Edit #1**
I've also tried `vdfuse`, but again, doesn't seem to be any way of "applying" the differencing disk.

Comment: @s_buttgereit As of today, August 2018, still no answer :(

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the only option is to open VirtualBox, "delete" the snapshot - so that it is combined with the vdi image, or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

I use a trick to do the job.

Create a new VM in VirtualBox with any OS you like (LiveCD is also OK).
Attach the vdi file to the VM in the storage settings. You can chooce any version in the snapshots. Though only the disk UUID is visible, you can chooce the right one according to the tree-like structure.
Boot the new VM and you can mount the partition as a block device.